# WPF ComboBox Bound List set on DropDownOpened Event

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

My problem is that the `ComboBox` is not displaying the value stored in its bound list.

Here is what I'm doing:

WPF:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" 
  DropDownOpened="deviceSelector_DropDownOpened"/>
```

Note that my `Window`'s `DataContext` is `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`.

C# code-behind:

```
public List<String> Devices { get; set; }

private void deviceSelector_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // the actual population of the list is occuring in another method 
  // as a result of a database query. I've confirmed that this query is
  // working properly and Devices is being populated.
  var dev = new List<String>();
  dev.Add("Device 1");
  dev.Add("Device 2");

  Devices = dev;
}
```

I have tried doing this with an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`, and I've also tried using a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`. Neither of these approaches have worked for me.

Any idea why my items aren't being displayed when I click the dropdown?

Comment: Since you're doing this in code behind anyway, why not set the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` directly?

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht tried that and it fixed my problem! Not sure why setting the `ItemsSource` in WPF didn't work, though. Care to explain?

Comment: I added an answer to try to help explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're doing this in code behind anyway, why not set the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` directly.

Now, I am not going to say this is the way it *should* be done in WPF (I would prefer the view's data to be loaded in a ViewModel), but it will solve your issue.

The reason why this isn't working is because your property doesn't inform the binding system when it changes. I know you said you tried it with `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, but that won't work unless your `View` looks like this:

```
public class MyView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<String> devices;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<String> Devices
    {
        get { return devices; }
        set 
        {
            devices = value;
            // add appropriate event raising pattern
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Devices"));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Likewise, using an `ObservableCollection` would only work like this:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<string> devices = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public IEnumerable<string> Devices { get { return devices; } }

private void deviceSelector_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    devices.Clear();
    devices.Add("Device 1");
    devices.Add("Device 2");
}
```

Either method should populate the `ComboBox`, and in a quick test I just ran, it worked.

**Edit to add `DependencyProperty` method**

One last way you can do this is with a `DependencyProperty` (as your `View` is a `DependencyObject`:

```
public class MyView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DevicesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Devices",
      typeof(List<string>),
      typeof(MainWindow),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public List<string> Devices
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(DevicesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DevicesProperty, value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following change (suggested by Abe Heidebrecht) fixed the problem, but I don't know why. Anyone willing to lend an explanation?

WPF:

```
<ComboBox DropDownOpened="deviceSelector_DropDownOpened"
  Name="deviceSelector"/>
```

C# code-behind:

```
private void deviceSelector_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var dev = new List<String>();
  dev.Add("Device 1");
  dev.Add("Device 2");

  deviceSelector.ItemsSource = dev;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here:

Try firing OnPropertyChanged when devices gets updated for the devices property, this should fix this. I have occasionally also had to set the mode:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Devices, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

On some controls.

Setting the itemssource on the control directly tells the control to use new items directly, without using the binding hooked up in the xaml. Updating the Devices property on the datacontext does not tell the combobox that the Devices property has changed so it won't update. The way to inform the combobox of the change is to fire OnPropertyChanged for the devices property when it gets changed.